# How To prevent forms from working in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am creating a project and I want to have a demo for users to test but they will have access to the admin area. I want to prevent any form with post method from working. I did that with Javascript by preventing the default methods.

I was wondering if there a better way to do so, in case the Javascript never loaded.

I was going to work with the view and the controller but its hassle when the project is big, doing it with a middleware is the best thing to go with in my opinion but I still couldn't reach out its logic. What would you guys recommend the logic should look like?

Comment: truthfully speaking the question is vague but lets work something out. Try to disable all ```Model->save()``` instances

Comment: well i dont wanna disable all modals if i want to , we can just prevent the boot from saving this will treger all the events to the database ,

the thing is i wanna disable the saving event in some routes thats why am trying to do it with middleware .

Comment: rocket science you have there buddy. if commenting  out save() is not the trick, i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Consider the @Flash answer, it's a good idea. Another way could be changing the method in controller. For example if you have a `store` method in `ExampleController` that saves/process the form, comment the lines inside the method like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    /*
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'display' => 'required',
    ]);

    $category = new Category();
    $category->parent_id = $request->parent_id;
    $category->name = $request->name;
    $category->display = $request->display;
    $category->save();

     return redirect()->route('category.add');
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a dummy user in your database and have a middleware in place(if you did not have it before).
- Save the demo user ID in a config file, let's say `config/app.php`.
- When someone visits your demo site, ask them to login and provide them the demo user credentials.
- Create a session after the login(which you would anyway) with that user and whenever a post or any request that would affect the database is made, check like below-

**Middleware Code:**

```
if(Auth::user()->id === config('app.dummy_user_id'){
    if($request->getMethod() === 'GET' || $request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS'){
       // for OPTIONS, you would play with the headers which I leave to you to edit
       return $next($request); 
    }else{
       return redirect()->back();
    }
}
// your further processing
return $next($request);
```